# MySQL Query to find users you are not friends with already, and order by mutual friend count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a social networking type of site I am working on in Laravel 4.2.

Basic Users table...

And a table to store friendships called "connections"

```
Connections
___________

user1_id
user2_id
status ('approved' or 'pending')
```

I am having a tough time trying to figure out how I would grab users and order by the mutual_friend count.

I am trying to build a page that shows a list of recommended friends which would just be exactly what I described above.

I am fairly new to Laravel.. but I would say this is more of an SQL problem though. Any help is appreciated.

Here is some code I am using for another search page.. but this is for comparing just 2 users so it may or may not help you.

```
public function mutualFriendCount($user1Id, $user2Id)
{
    $user1Friends = array();
    $user2Friends = array();

    //build array of friends for user1 and user2 
    $user1Connections = Connection::whereStatus('approved')
        ->where(function($query) use($user1Id){
           $query->orWhere('user1_id', '=', $user1Id);
           $query->orWhere('user2_id', '=', $user1Id);
        })->orderBy('created_at')->select('user1_id' , 'user2_id')->get();


    foreach ($user1Connections as $user1Connection) {
        if($user1Connection->user1_id != $user1Id && $user1Connection->user1_id != $user2Id) {
            $user1Friends[] = $user1Connection->user1_id;
        }
        if($user1Connection->user2_id != $user1Id && $user1Connection->user2_id != $user2Id) {
            $user1Friends[] = $user1Connection->user2_id;
        }
    }

    $user2Connections = Connection::whereStatus('approved')
        ->where(function($query) use($user2Id){
           $query->orWhere('user1_id', '=', $user2Id);
           $query->orWhere('user2_id', '=', $user2Id);
        })->orderBy('created_at')->select('user1_id' , 'user2_id')->get();


    foreach ($user2Connections as $user2Connection) {
        if($user2Connection->user1_id != $user1Id && $user2Connection->user1_id != $user2Id) {
            $user2Friends[] = $user2Connection->user1_id;
        }
        if($user2Connection->user2_id != $user1Id && $user2Connection->user2_id != $user2Id) {
            $user2Friends[] = $user2Connection->user2_id;
        }
    }

    //compare the arrays and return the count
    return count(array_intersect($user1Friends, $user2Friends));

}
```

Comment: so basically given a "user1_id", you want to find all of that person's friends's friends, who aren't already friends with user1? E.g. Fred is friends with George whois friends with Harry. If Harry isn't a friend of Fred, then include Harry in the results?

Comment: @MarcB you got it.. given a user_id. Keep in mind that if I have user_id of 7.. that can show up user1_id or user2_id.. just depends who sent the friend request. There will never be 2 records in the connections table with the same 2 user id's though.. eg.. if there is a record with user1_id = 7 and user2_id = 3... there will never be another where user1_id = 3 and user2_id = 7. hope this helps

Comment: basically just a 3-way self-join. users -> users as friends -> users as friends_of_friends, then `where users.user1_id not exists friends_of_friends.user2_id` kinda thing.

Comment: @MarcB Not sure I am following you with that one

Comment: first join gives you Fred's friends. second join gives the friends of Fred's friends. The 3rd join lets you find all of those friends-of-friends who AREN'T friends with Fred already.